# Can't seem to understand the error after a few days

Tags: java, string

Hello So i'm doing the following for practice:

- **wordcount:** This method should accept a reference to a String object as an argument and return the number of words contained in the object
- **arrayToString:** This method adepts a char array as an argument and converts it to a String object. The method should return a reference to the String object.
- **Mostfrequent:** This method accepts a reference to a String object as an argument and returns the character that occurs the most frequently in the object.
- **ReplacaSubstring:** This method accepts three references to String objects as arguments. Lett's call them stringl, string2, and string3. It searches stringl for all occurrences of string2. When it finds an occurrence of string2, it replaces it with string3, For example, suppose the three arguments have the following values:

  - String1: "the dog jumped over the fence"
  - String2: "the"
  - String3: "that"

  With these three arguments, the method would return a reference to a String object with the value "that dog jumped over that fence".

My following code (Main):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String string1 = "the dog jumped over the fence";
        String string2 = "the";
        String string3 = "that";
        char[] charArray = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g',
                            'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p',
                            'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v','w', 'x','y', 'z'};

        // wordCount method
        int numberOfWords = wordCount(string1);
        System.out.println("Count the number of words: " + string1);
        System.out.println("Number of words given string: " + numberOfWords);

        // arrayToString method
        String character = arrayToString(charArray);
        System.out.print("\nGiven characters in the array:");

        for(int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++)

        System.out.print(charArray[i] + " ");
        System.out.print("\nString from given character array: " + character);

        // mostFrequent method
        char mostOccurrence = mostFrequent(string1);
        System.out.println("\nGiven string to get the most occured characters: " + string1);
        System.out.println("The most occured character in given string: " + mostOccurrence);

        //replaceSustring method
        String string = replaceSubstring(string1, string2, string3);
        System.out.println("\nGiven string to modify: " + string1);
        System.out.println("Replace for: " +string2);
        System.out.println("After replacing, the new string: " + string);
    }
}
```

With the following error for this class:

```
C:\Users\carlosm\Desktop\New folder\MiscellaneousString.java:1: error: class MiscellaneousStringClass is public, should be declared in a file named MiscellaneousStringClass.java
public class MiscellaneousStringClass {
       ^
1 error
```

And regular class file:

```
public class MiscellaneousStringClass {

    int numberOfWords;
    /* method should accept a reference to a string object
     * as an argument and return the number of words contain
     * in the object
     */

     private static int wordCount(String string1) {
        int number = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < string1.length(); i++) {
            char ch = string1.charAt(i);

            if(Character.isWhitespace(ch)) {
                number = number + 1;
            }
        }

        return number + 1;
     }

     /* method should accept a char array as an argument and convert i to a string object.
      * The method should return to the string object.
      */
      private static String arrayToString(char[] charArray) {
          return String.valueOf(charArray);
      }

      /* method accepts a reference to a string object as an argument
       * and returns the character that occurs the most frequently
       * in the object.
       */

       private static char mostFrequent(String string1) {
           char mostOccurrence = ' ';
           int most = 0;
           int j;
           for(int i = 0; i < string1.length(); i++) {
               int count = 0;
               char ch = string1.charAt(i);

               for(j = 0; j < string1.length(); j++) {
                   if(ch == string1.charAt(j))count = count + 1;
               }

               if(count >= most) {
                   most = count;
                   mostOccurrence = ch;
                }
            }

            return mostOccurrence;
        }

    /* method accepts three references to string object as arguments.
     * Call them string1, string2, and string3; when it finds an occurrence
     * of string2, it replaces it with string 3.
     */

     private static String replaceSubstring(String string1, String string2, String string3) {
        return string1.replaceAll(string2, string3);
    }
}
```

And following error for this class:

```
C:\Users\carlosm\Desktop\New folder\Demo.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
        int numberOfWords = wordCount(string1);
                            ^
  symbol:   method wordCount(String)
  location: class Demo
C:\Users\carlosm\Desktop\New folder\Demo.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
        String character = arrayToString(charArray);
                           ^
  symbol:   method arrayToString(char[])
  location: class Demo
C:\Users\carlosm\Desktop\New folder\Demo.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
        char mostOccurrence = mostFrequent(string1);
                              ^
  symbol:   method mostFrequent(String)
  location: class Demo
C:\Users\carlosm\Desktop\New folder\Demo.java:32: error: cannot find symbol
        String string = replaceSubstring(string1, string2, string3);
                        ^
  symbol:   method replaceSubstring(String,String,String)
  location: class Demo
4 errors
```

Any help will do.

Comment: The message are pretty explicit IMHO, you probably should read a basic [java tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/)

Answer (score 2):

1. First make sure that any Java public class name and its file name matches.
2. Make sure your class having the `main()` method has access to the other class and imports it properly to use the other class's methods. For example, if Class `Demo` is trying to use methods of class `MiscellaneousStringClass`, resolve dependencies and make sure the class & its methods are visible in the `Demo` class.
3. `MiscellaneousStringClass` methods have to public in order get accessed from other classes.

Answer (score 2):

In order to call a static method defined in another class, you need to prefix it by the class name (and to `import` the class). In your case, in the class `Demo`:

```
MiscellaneousStringClass.wordCount(string1);
```

And so on...

Then a public class needs to be declared in a file .java and in a folder which follow the package hierarchy (in your case there is no package).

If you want to simplify, you can include the `MiscellaneousStringClass` into the `Demo.java` file, **without** the `public` declaration.

Comment: Yea thats what i was thinking of was simply putting both class together into a single Java file

Comment: It's just a simplification for you, but it make sense to keep the _utility_ class in its own file: just rename the classby removing the trailing `...Class` and it should compile.

Comment: So I composed all my files together into one but for some reason still obtaining those 4 errors defined above. Sorry to be a nuisance but what exactly am i doing wrong if all my classes are in a single java file?

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Demo {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    String string1 = "the dog jumped over the fence";
    String string2 = "the";
    String string3 = "that";
    char[] charArray = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g',
                        'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p',
                        'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v','w', 'x','y', 'z'};

    // wordCount method
    int numberOfWords = MiscellaneousStringClass.wordCount(string1);
    System.out.println("Count the number of words: " + string1);
    System.out.println("Number of words given string: " + numberOfWords);

    // arrayToString method
    String character = MiscellaneousStringClass.arrayToString(charArray);
    System.out.print("\nGiven characters in the array:");

    for(int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++)

    System.out.print(charArray[i] + " ");
    System.out.print("\nString from given character array: " + character);

    // mostFrequent method
    char mostOccurrence = MiscellaneousStringClass.mostFrequent(string1);
    System.out.println("\nGiven string to get the most occured characters: " + string1);
    System.out.println("The most occured character in given string: " + mostOccurrence);

    //replaceSustring method
    String string = MiscellaneousStringClass.replaceSubstring(string1, string2, string3);
    System.out.println("\nGiven string to modify: " + string1);
    System.out.println("Replace for: " +string2);
    System.out.println("After replacing, the new string: " + string);
  }
}
```

You are using two public class. That's why you should write these classes in separate files. Name of the file should be name of the class

Comment: I do have it as 2 separate files.

Comment: Edit: never mind fixed the problem which was i had privat for withing my public class thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So you need to learn how to read the error message presented. I will insert newlines so as to be able to refer to each components of the message ...

```
C:\Users\carlosm\Desktop\New folder\MiscellaneousString.java:1:
error: class MiscellaneousStringClass is public, 
should be declared in a file named MiscellaneousStringClass.java

public class MiscellaneousStringClass {
```

The first 'line' of the error message names the file where the compilation error has occurred.

For this error it is

C:\Users\carlosm\Desktop\New folder\**MiscellaneousString**.java

The **:1:** indicates that the compiler discovered the error on line 1 of that file.

The error then goes on to say as this contains a *public* class called *MiscellaneousStringClass* Java insists that the filename (excluding the .java extention) and the public class use the same name.

So you have two options ...

1. Rename the class in your file to be **MiscellaneousString**
2. Rename the file to be **MiscellaneousStringClass.java**

I would go be inclined to go with the first option as using the word 'Class' in a Java Class is overkill and a little odd.

You will then have new errors, see Abbé Résina's answer on how to call the static members of your class.

Comment: Yea i seen i was dunce for doing that and quickly changed it. Thank you for the response.

Comment: Don't be hard on yourself, if it was easy, everyone would be doing it!

Comment: I'm still not understanding how im still obtaining the 4 errors above even when i added them to the same file the other class (not the main) not having public so it would be less of an issue yet still get the same issues. Any comment on that?

Comment: Did you  get sorted out?

Comment: Hey yea i did. I ended up sorting all my classes in one file and was still getting the same 4 errors but i realized that with the non main class, the inner classes were set to private so i just deleted the private class and left "static classname" to make it function.